# Did the Meta Community Bulletin Board die?

Tags: discussion, community-bulletin

Came across this post somehow:

[Nailing it up on your Community Bulletin Board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board)

Which, in turn, took me to a host of other questions with screen prints of said bulletin board.  Yet, I can't remember seeing this bulletin board in the 4-something months I've been here.

Did it die, or does it just not get used much?  If it's dead, should there be some mention of its death so anyone who comes across those posts knows it's a "Legacy" thing?

Comment: The announcement of its removal would probably be an appropriate subject for a post on the Community Bulletin Board.

Comment: +1.  Lord knows I love a good smarta$$ comment.  :o)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Good idea. Adding.

Comment: The 3 answers below are all good, factual and included different bits of info.  Couldn't really pick one over the other so I just upvoted them all.

Answer (score 4):

It does exist, for example on other sites like [SciFi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

So it isn't fully dead, it just seems like noone has posted anything to it on SO recently

Comment: on programmers, it's COHHUNITY BULLETIN :-)

Comment: LOL Wow that is **hard** to read @KateGregory haha

Comment: Actually on second look it's COHHUNKY BULLETIN

Answer (score 3):

From [the post you linked to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board):

> There are two missing pieces though:
>
> 1. It's not particularly functional for Stack Overflow, because there's no way to create per-tag events. Apart from things like Meetups and major cleanup efforts, there aren't a lot of events that are worth intruding on every single reader's view.
> 2. The best part - scheduled events - is moderator-only.

There were two stages planned for the implementation of that feature: the first stage (which would suffice for nearly all sites on the network) was a fairly light-weight event-and-meta view driven mostly by meta-votes and direct moderator intervention. The second stage - making it functional for Stack Overflow - required deeper integration with the site itself and the (generally tag/topic-focused) communities on it. Sadly, this latter part was never finished and eventually ended up blocked by [a larger project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange) which could/should/may integrate with it in some form.

For the time being, you'll see the board pop up on SO (and MSO) occasionally when there's a blog post or (rarely) when a moderator or team member adds an "event" to the schedule.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where you're expecting to see it. If you're talking about Stack Overflow, I don't believe there is anything to currently be displayed on the Community Bulletin. Generally only recent blog posts and recent [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts show up on it for Stack Overflow (since not all Meta Stack Overflow questions would necessarily be specific to the Stack Overflow community). I'm not sure what the time threshold is for how long they stay there.

It's definitely not dead, though. For example, it shows up on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/).