# Missing last activity date

Tags: support, last-activity

So, there's a modification to a question and I was curious what the change was:

> [image: from last active questions]

But when I got to the question, there was no 'last activity' on the right hand side:

> [image: right hand side]

Though you could see it if you scrolled down to the last edit:

> [image: edited by section]

I was expecting something like this on the side:

> [image: expected side bar]

Note the 'active today'

The question in question with the lack of active activity is [Nailing it up on your Community Bulletin Board](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130892/nailing-it-up-on-your-community-bulletin-board)

Comment: @Stijn I'll agree with the dup, though I'll also note that like the first person asking the question it is a surprising thing to see (or not see) the activity field on question but not another. (and thank you for the stylistic edit for the boxes around the images - I'll remember that one).